# WooCommerce автоподставление данных на странице оплаты

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт, воспользовался стандартной регистрацией. Всё хорошо, но вот данные (адрес, номер, имя/фамилия, почтовый индект и т.д) не подставляются автоматически. Смысл регистрации пропадает, нужно что-бы подставлялись. Как это сделать? Если я через админку захожу в управление пользователем, там все эти данные есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал сейчас на своём втором сайте WordPress сделать тоже самое. Итог - всё работает и подставляется, что там не так?

Comment: Стандартный шаблон чекаута подставляет все как надо. Если его изменили, то тут уже ваши проблемы)

Comment: Да, походу это реально так. Но я не могу понять,  с помощью чего. Плагина вроде-бы не какого нету. https://www.upload.ee/image/11593719/_________30-04-2020_003151.png

Comment: В теме в папке woocommerce ищите)